# Implement multiple roles on the same data in MVC (ASP)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Example:

We have two user types.

- SupplierUser
- FactoryUser

They both interface with basically the same data, but in general FactoryUsers can edit much more of this information than the SupplierUser.

Using ASP.NET 4.5, I am implementing all of this using MVC.

Some summarized use cases: (Assume logged in)

*FactoryUser:*

- Editable messages page, which shows suppliers their latest announcements.
- Order confirmation page, and order view page.
- Supplier edit page (for updating addresses etc of multiple suppliers)

*SupplierUser:*
 - Can see messages from specific Factory.
 - Can create orders, send and view.
 - Can edit their own information

As you can see this is just a lot of editing of information with various permission. My question is, *Where should I be starting the separations?*

With regards to:

1. Models  -  I think this one stays as one with the database
2. ViewModels - Do I write different views for each role? If so, 2 files/classes?
3. Controllers - Same, do I write different functions?? Classes? If so then what is the point is having [Authorize role], just to protect from unauthorized access & not intended to split?
4. Views - Do I try to use the same views for most parts and just somehow include logic about if they have "edit" buttons or not?
5. Partial Views - Can they be used for the "edit" buttons that may or may not be on the view?
6. View Layouts - ?
7. Filters - I can do some fancy logic and put everything in entirely 2 different folders (the whole MVC) and then split it at route/authorize level
8. Routing - ?

At each one of the above, I can see a possibility to split the logic depending on the type of user. But of course, I want to do this in the simplest and most sane way possible.

Is there some document somewhere which specifies how this should be done, or otherwise any wise people out there who have done this before and encountered all the issues?

Thanks
(first question!)

Comment: {Authorize] just allows or disallows access to the Action/Controller. You can check the user Role in View and hide or show different actions based on the role,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create features. e.g `View Orders, Create Order, Update Order, Delete Order`

These `features` will then be assigned to a `Role` - and the Role can be assigned to a `User`

So the DB will look something like this:

[image]

Now when the user logs in, you read all the features assigned to the user and save them in the session (Create a SessionHandler Class).

```
// Login Function - You can call from Controller
public UserDTO Login(string username, string password)
{
 var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Username == username && s.Password == password);

if(user == null) return null; // login failed

var model = new UserDTO()
{
    UserId = user.UserId,
    Features = user.Role.Features.Select(s => s.FeatureName).ToList()
};


return model;

}
```

Sample of UserDTO class

```
public class UserDTO
{
     public int UserId {get;set;}
     public List<string> Features {get;set;}
}
```

Sample of `SessionHandler`

```
public class SessionHandler
{
    private const string SessionKey = "UserSession";

    public static UserDTO UserSession
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionKey] != null
                       ? (UserDTO)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionKey]
                       : null;
        }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionKey] = value; }
    }
}
```

So in your controller call the `Login` Function and assign to `UserSession` in `SessionHandler`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
   var user = Login(model.username, model.password);

   if(user == null) return View(model);

   SessionHandler.UserSession = user;

   // TODO: redirect to Home Page - after login

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Then what you can do in your views is check if the user can perform a certain action, so e.g. if you are on the View Orders page - you can hide the Create Order Button if user does NOT have permission:

```
    @model WhateverDTO

    // Check if user has Create Order Feature in Role 

    @if (SessionHandler.UserSession.Features.Contains("Create Order"))
    {
// Yes, User has permission - then Render the Button

     <button> Create Order </button>

    }
```

Also you can add checks in the Controller(Server side) - Which will provide extra security to your application, using the Authorise Attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        if (httpContext.Session == null)
            return false;

        // Checking Authenticaiton
        var userSettings = SessionHandler.UserSession;
        if (userSettings == null)
            return true;

        //Checking Authorization
        if (Roles.Length == 0)
            return true;


        var actionFeatures = Roles.Split(',');
        if (!actionFeatures.Any(s => userSettings.Features.Contains(s)))
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You do not have permission to perform this action.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then decorate your Actions,

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Create Order")]
// Pass feature name for Roles - if user doesn't have permission to Create Order - the "You do not have permission to perform this action." exception will get thrown
public ActionResult CreateOrder()
{
  return View(new CreateOrderDTO());
}

[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Create Order")]
// Pass feature name for Roles - if user doesn't have permission to Create Order - the "You do not have permission to perform this action." exception will get thrown
public ActionResult CreateOrder(CreateOrderDTO model)
{

  return View(model);
}
```

The good thing about the above method - is that you can add as many user Roles as you need - without changing the Code.

---

**Models - I think this one stays as one with the database**

Models are same - same DB same models

**ViewModels - Do I write different views for each role? If so, 2 files/classes?**

No, don't complicate things - use same ViewModel / DTO

**Controllers - Same, do I write different functions?? Classes? If so then what is the point is having [Authorize role], just to protect from unauthorized access & not intended to split?**

No need for separate actions/views or controllers

**Views - Do I try to use the same views for most parts and just somehow include logic about if they have "edit" buttons or not?**

Yes, use same views - Hide/Show actions based on User Role/ Feature

**Partial Views - Can they be used for the "edit" buttons that may or may not be on the view?**

No need for Partial Views for buttons

**View Layouts - ?
Filters - I can do some fancy logic and put everything in entirely 2 different folders (the whole MVC) and then split it at route/authorize level
Routing - ?**

No

Comment: Could you give me a bit of direction as to ideally where these files should be placed? (MVC structure wise)

Comment: I've implemented this and it works, Thanks :) Let me know about where I should be placing the classes with regards to namespace/folder/file

Comment: @Worthy7 that totally depends on the Architecture of your application - SessionHandler should be added to the MVC Web Application in a subfolder e.g. Helpers. other than that if you have a separate project for DTOs Enums, then place them in there - otherwise add them to a subfolder in the MVC Web Project.